# Jenkins - Mark build as success

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

I use Jenkins to build my maven Java app then create Docker image and push it. After all of that I have try-catch where I Try to stop and remove the container if it's already running - If not it should just skip it and run the new Image - It works but always marks the build as failed. I tried to change the build status, but apparently that is not possible.

Here is my pipeline:

```
node {
stage('Clone repository') {
    git branch: 'main', credentialsId: 'realsnack-git', url: 'https://github.com/Realsnack/Java-rest-api.git'
}

stage('Build maven project') {
    sh './mvnw clean package'
}

stage('Build docker image') {
    sh 'docker build -t 192.168.1.27:49153/java-restapi:latest .'
}

stage('Push image') {
    sh 'docker push 192.168.1.27:49153/java-restapi:latest'
}

try {
    stage('Remove old container') {
        sh 'docker stop java-rest_api && docker rm java-rest_api'
    }
} catch(all) {
    sh 'No container to remove - runnning it anyway'
} finally {
    stage('Run image') {
        sh 'docker run -d --name java-rest_api -p 8081:8081 192.168.1.27:49153/java-restapi:latest'
    }
}
}
```

Comment: Wondering why you want to run the java app docker container after the build? Is that because you want to run some integration tests?
I might help you to write a better pipeline by using Jenkins docker DSL.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`docker stop` will fail if it fails to stop the container.

You can solve the issue in one of the two following ways:

1. Check that there is a running container before attempting to stop it:

```
sh "if [[ docker ps -a | grep java-rest_api ]]; docker stop java-rest_api; fi"
```

2. Ignore the docker error:

```
sh "docker stop java-rest_api || true"
```